# Getting large number of small files (images) from FTP using python

Tags: python, ftp

I have a following problem to solve:

Camera takes a picture roughly three times a second and saves it on a FTP server. I would like to access the FTP server using python, download images and do some further processing using OpenCV. It wouldn't be a challenge if the system could work offline, but I would like to achieve online processing i.e. I want to download files with such rate to be able to do live processing (or at least live preview for start).

Currently downloading one file takes about one second or more. Files are small (50 kB) and I guess that the issue here is the overhead caused by downloading files one by one. Is there a way to download e.g. 10 or 100 files from FTP at once? This would introduce some delay to my processing, but hopefully I could get much better fluency. Is there maybe other solution to my problem?

The code I have so far:

```
from ftplib import FTP
from StringIO import StringIO
import numpy as np
import cv2

ftp = FTP("ftp.name")
ftp.login("login", "passwd")
ftp.cwd("camera")
#Getting listing
ls = []
ftp.retrlines('MLSD', ls.append)

for entry in ls:
    prop = entry.split(";")

    #Skip if directory
    if prop[0].split("=")[1] == "dir":
        continue

    #Getting file
    r = StringIO()
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR' + filename, r.write) #filename starts with space character

    nparr = np.fromstring(r.getvalue(), np.uint8)
    img_np = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

    cv2.imshow("image", img_np)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Comment: You could try multiple connections in parallel, assuming it's not bandwidth that's limiting you. Say one thread that periodically lists the files, finds any new ones that appeared and feeds enumerated filenames to input queue. A pool of threads, each with is own connection, that take a file name from the input queue, download the file and put the number + data into output queue(s). The main thread is then responsible for fetching from the output queue(s), putting the frames back in order (that's why we enumerated) and processing them.

Comment: IMHO you could drop the OpenCV part + tag from this question, it's not really relevant. What you seem to be asking is "How to increase throughput of fetching multiple files from FTP", or something along those lines.